# Testing Xcode projects saved using Google FileStream

Tags: xcode, filestream

I am a high school CS teacher teaching C++ with Xcode.  In the past, I have used Google Backup and Sync such that my kids shared a Google Drive folder with me, saved all their work locally in their Google Drive folder, and synced this folder with Google Drive's cloud.  Worked like a charm.  Now, our school has transitioned to Google FileStream, which works differently.  Google Drive is now treated as a mounted volume and by default does not copy synced folders, but provides links to them on the cloud, so they appear to be local, but are in fact not.  I am able to have my kids set their class folder in "offline mode" so that they can use it as before, maintaining local file copies as well as syncing with Google Drive's cloud.  However, I just discovered that this results in a "permission denied" error when trying to execute their code.  Projects build, but do not run.

I had them move their project folders to their desktop, and they build and run just fine.  When saved on the FileStream mount, even attempting to run a successfully built project through terminal results in the same "permission denied" response.  So I am 100% sure the issue here is trying to run executable code from the FileStream mounted folder.

Any thoughts here?  Is there a Mac security setting somewhere that I cannot find that will allow this?  Or is this a Google Drive thing?  I can always have them work locally, then copy the project over, but that is a real pain for them and me with grading from home.

Comment: Good question, but you might get better answers on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Reposted there, thanks.